# boost asio write operation on client is blocked when server down

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I want  implement a synchronous tcp client using boost::asio.

scenario:

- client: synchronize tcp client, send data to server in a loop
- server: reveive data from client

And connection can be rebuild when socket is unavailable.

### Client

```
io_service ios;
shared_ptr<socket> sp_sock(new socket(ios));
endpoint ep(address,port);
error_code ec;
sp_sock->connect(ep,ec);
if(ec)
{
   return;
}

for(;;)
{
    error_code ec;
    boost::asio::write(*sp_sock,buffer("hello world"),ec);
    if(ec)
    {            
        reconnect_socket();
    }
    cout<<ec.message()<<endl; 
    sleep_for_a_while();       
}
```

### Problem

client will connect to server, then send "hello world" to server. But when i shutdown server with "ctrl+c", the problem raise:

Write operation still work without any error throwed, and `ec.message() = "success"`.
After several write operation, the thread is blocked forever at write.

Maybe the write function put the data into the buffer, then return immediately, and write is blocked when the buffer is full?

In general, how to check socket is writable or not, or throw an error when server down, so that the program can try to rebuild the connection when server comes up again.

Comment: The only reliable enough way to detect whether your peer is alive or not is to implement some kind of ping or heartbeat on the application level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your client code, it is behaving correctly as a TCP socket implements reliable in-order delivery of the byte stream. Your client does not realize the server is unresponsive because that's not such a simple task, there are many entities between your client and server applications.

You may wish to enable [TCP keep alive](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html). Though be careful as it too is not a silver bullet, it merely indicates the TCP stack on both ends is alive and well; which says nothing about the application availability. The various timeous are also somewhat tricky to configure for all environments.

The most flexible option is to implement a heartbeat protocol in your client and server, which can be fully tailored to your application's performance requirements.